# MacBook Pro mid 2009 running windows 10 GPU issues

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, macbook, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

This issue is about a MacBook Pro mid 2009 with 2 graphics cards (integrated - 9400M, dedicated - 9600M GT)

Long story:

- does not install OS X (stop sign or reset depending on the version I'm trying to install)
- an OS X Mountain Lion has been installed on the laptop but it was always resetting during OS bootup and before next boot an error screen in 7 languages would appear informing of previous issue and process repeats (no matter how much I tried to find out why the laptop was resetting I did not succeed)
- I got fed up of trying to install Mac OS and installed Windows 10 (the irony - wasn't able to install Mac OS on a Mac but windows had no issues)
- Bootcamp drivers have been installed (for some devices the driver had to be manually selected - bluetooth, SMU)

Problem:

- none of the 2 video cards work properly

Details:

- the 9400m board appears in device manager as "Microsft basic visual adapter" (detected by GPU-z as 9400m)
- I tried to select the drivers manually but unsuccessfully - after the driver install restart the screen is black and after 20 seconds it restarts and goes into a loop or the device manager driver update fails and automatically starts the uninstaller for the nVidia video drivers
- the 9600m GT board appears correctly installed in device manager, but with error 43 on the details - there are very good chances that the board is dead / needs reballing / need capacitors changed - problems on this model are many

Bonus:

- When I run CPU-z, GSOD with WDF_ERROR when it loads "sensors"
- When I run CPU-z in safe mode, it's all good

**Any thoughts, ideas or suggestions?**

**EDIT**

I have installed MacOS 10.10 via an older hdd's recovery tool.
The Mac boots only with nv_disable=1 -> the 9600m GT card is dead.
MacOS cannot even play 480p video on youtube with the nv_disabled tag
Installed Widnwos 10 via Bootcamp. Exact same issues as in EFI install.

**PS** If this helps, the HWID of the 9400m is PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_0866&SUBSYS_00AF106B&REV_B1

Google searches did not help. VEN_10DE&DEV_0866 drivers did not work. The display would turn black and the laptop would restart.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install OS X boot camp utility.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204923#download

Also, my guess as to why OS X won’t install has to do with the drive not being partitioned correctly. Boot to recovery and use internet recovery to run disk utility. Format the drive to OS X journaled

Comment: There's no Internet recovery on an 09 Mac. DVD only in those days, though  09 is on the cusp of being able to properly install from USB. Worth trying the BC instal, but I wouldn't have high hopes, as again, the 09 isn't supported for Win10.

Comment: You’re right, I was thinking my wife’s MBP was an 09 but it’s an 11. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got one of these 17" 2009 mbps working with an early version of lion osx, in which you can select the gpu mode, battery life or high performance, it will crash if high performance mode is selected because the 9600gt is bad .  Choosing battery life it stays on 9400m.  Later versions of lion and any subsequent osx will boot loop if the 9600gt has failed I think because they do the auto graphics switching and they switch to the 9600gt part way through the installation.  I found supply voltage to chip was a bit low compared to the schematic I found and I fixed that by replacing the capacitor  which fixed the voltage on the 9600gt supply but unfortunately the problem remained with the discrete graphics and so it probably is a problem with the 9600gt chip.  You can make a bootable usb of any osx or do it via target disc mode if you have a firewire 800 cable and another mac or use the dvd, via an internal or external dvd drive.  Boot loop is gpu problem, stop sign means the machine is too old for the osx.